# Is $\lim_{t\to0^+}[f(t)*g(t)]=\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)*\lim_{t\to0^+}g(t)?$

Tags: real-analysis

> If $\ast:[0,1]\times [0,1]\to[0,1]$ is continuous, $f,g:(0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ are continuous s.t. $\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t),\lim_{t\to0^+}g(t)$ exist then can we conclude that $$\lim_{t\to0^+}[f(t)*g(t)]=\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)*\lim_{t\to0^+}g(t)?$$

From the symmetry of the functions it is appearing to be true but I could not prove it using sequencial criterion? Can someone help me ?

**My attempt:** Let $f',g'$ be the continuous extensions of $f,g$ respectively on $[0,\infty).$ Since $f',g'$ are continuous on $[0,\infty)$ so is $(f',g'):[0,\infty)\to[0,1]\times[0,1].$ By the rule of compositions of continuous functions we see that $f'*g':[0,\infty)\to[0,1]$ is continuous. Thus $\lim_{t\to0^+}[f'(t)*g'(t)]=f'(0)*g'(0)$ i.e. $\lim_{t\to0^+}[f(t)*g(t)]=\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)*\lim_{t\to0^+}g(t).$

Is this a correct attempt?

Comment: Provided the limits of $f$ and $g$ at $0$ exist, the result holds true.

Comment: this is true $\iff$ you proved the limits exists and they are finite: $lim_{t \to 0^{+}} f(t), \lim_{t \to 0^{+}} g(t) \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Need each limit to exist as $x \to 0^+.$ That's more than continuous on $(0,\infty).$

Comment: Is the attempt I added correct?